# Javascript: How to check string type?

Tags: javascript, string, types

So I would like to know what's inside the string for example:

```
var str = "a"; // Letter
var str = "1"; // Number
var str = "["; // Special
var str = "@"; // Special
var str = "+"; // Special
```

Is there any pre defined javascript function for this? Otherwise I will make it with regex :)

Comment: You might want to check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric before delving into Regular Expressions for numeric validation

Comment: I don't think CIRK is wanting to do actual numeric validation, rather just determine the type of a single character. Certainly, that's the impression I get from the examples in their post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (/^[a-zA-Z]$/.test(str)){
    // letter
} else if (/^[0-9]$/.test(str)){
    // number
} else {
    // other
};
```

Of course this only matches one character so 'AA' would end up in the `//other` section.

Answer (score 2):

They are all strings...

There isn't anything built in that will do what you want.

A regex may be a good solution, though you have not really provided enough information for one.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn - Some people, when confronted with a problem, think
“I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isNaN(string)){
   //yes is a string
}
```